# Android apk crashes on a few devices running on Android 4.4

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash-reports

This apk is my recent update in production without proguard obfuscation or any optimization. Just in case so someone don't suggest it may be proguard related. However, I recently compiled with API 20: Android 4.4 Kitkat wear and set my target as API 21: L Preview. Eclipse compiled it successfully. I don't know if this could be a problem. I'm not sure if there are devices running on the L Preview yet.
According to my google crash report all the devices that crashed where devices running on Android 4.4. This affected only less than 1% of my Android 4.4 installs. It stops working when the affected users try to open the app.

Below is the stack trace. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.myproject.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:189)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1495)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3453)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4816)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the lines included in the stack trace:

Lines 188-191 are:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0).edit();
editor.putString("lastKnownLatitude", String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
editor.putString("lastKnownLongitude", String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
editor.commit();
```

The lines are within `listview.setOnItemClickListener` and after `editor.commit` it starts a new activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @panini No... that question describes how to find the stack trace. He has his posted.

Comment: And what **is** on line 189 of your `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @mikeyaworski the answer also links to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) which describes what to do with the stack trace. as it is, the stack trace posted doesn't help as we have no idea what MainActivity.java looks like.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Thanks but for legal reasons I may not be able to post the source. However the MainActivity.java uses google fused location services and has a simple listView. There's nothing complex and works for 99.5% of other devices

Comment: @panini How can this be a duplicate when It's a specific stack trace  question

Comment: @panini I saw that. First of all, you should link to that question if you think this is a duplicate of that. Not the question in between these "duplicates". And secondly, this question is supposed to be about the Android 4.4 thing (I think).

Comment: @user3144836 Your stack trace is very easy to read. On line 189 of your MainActivity.java, you are running into a NullPointerException. The question is *why*? Is it because of Android 4.4? But still, your question could be a duplicate of that if it was only about the stack trace. Reading the stack trace is a duplicate even if it's only your own stack trace. But this question isn't entirely a duplicate.

Comment: If you can't post the code, all we can do is tell you to learn how to read the stack trace.

Comment: @323go Lines 188-191 is:  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0).edit();
      editor.putString("lastKnownLatitude", String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
      editor.putString("lastKnownLongitude", String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
      editor.commit(); withing listview.setOnItemClickListener and after editor.commit it starts a new activity

Comment: Looks like `mCurrentLocation` is null. Check that out.

Comment: Thanks I'll make some changes to my code on line 189. I don't have to use SharedPreferences.Editor. I'll get around it. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll see what happens after I send in a new update to production.

Comment: SharedPreferences isn't your problem. It's location.